# background:transparent is not working in ie7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

By default one background color is applying for thead th.i am removing the css using 
`background:transparent`.But `transparent` working in ie9 and ie8 but not support in ie7.

I also tried `background:none` but no use.i want to remove the background css for thead.

I am trying for this but without success.

Comment: No it's not working, you're right.

Comment: the default background should be something like transparent, so you can try `background:initial` or `background:rgba(0,0,0,0)`?

Comment: I don't think `RGBA` works in IE8 or lower.

Comment: background-color:transparant only working but it's not supporting in ie7.i tried background:intial no use.

Comment: please tell me how to remove the css for thead in ie7.

Comment: try to turn your border-size into an extra padding (or margin) of same size. if it is space you are looking for.

Comment: @user3494837 What element is the background defined on? The table? In that case, you should remove that, and apply it to the tbody instead.